# 3D reflection of a ray on a cylindrical mirror

Tags: optics, reflection

I am trying to calculate the reflection of a ray on a cylindrical mirror in a three-dimensional space. To achieve this, can I apply the laws of reflection separately in xy and xz planes (as in the attached picture), or is it more complicated than that? (my intuition say "yes" but it has often been wrong in the past)

[image]

If so, is it true regardless of the shape of the mirror ?

Comment: What is your description for the ray? Is it (origin, direction) or something else?

Comment: The ray can have any origin in the space. For illustrative purposes, I have represented with dotted lines the projection of a ray on xy and xz planes

Comment: The projections of the equal incidence and reflection angles on a plane parallel to the normal (here the xy-plane) are equal . But the projections of the equal incidence and reflection angles on a plane oblique to the normal (here the xz-plane) are not equal in general. For a pictorial counterexample take a look here https://imgur.com/fWYeesJ

Answer (score 1):

If an incident ray with direction $\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}$ is reflected on a surface with normal direction $\boldsymbol{\hat{n}}$, then the direction of the emitted ray is $$\boldsymbol{\hat{e}} = \boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}} - 2 (\boldsymbol{\hat{\imath}}\cdot \boldsymbol{\hat{n}}) \boldsymbol{\hat{n}}  $$

<sub>See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13263/3301) for reference. Note that $\cdot$ is the vector dot product.</sub>

All you need in your case is the cylinder normal direction $\boldsymbol{\hat{n}}$ at the incident point $\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}$. If the cylinder lies along the $\boldsymbol{\hat{z}}$ direction and through a point $\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}_C$, then the normal direction is

$$ \boldsymbol{\hat{n}} = {\rm unitvector}\left\{ (\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}-\boldsymbol{\vec{r}_C}) - \boldsymbol{\hat{z}} ( \boldsymbol{\hat{z}} \cdot (\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}-\boldsymbol{\vec{r}_C})) \right\} $$

The last part is finding out where the incident point $\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}$ given the ray and the cylinder. This is given in [Slide 3](https://mrl.nyu.edu/~dzorin/rend05/lecture2.pdf) of this ray tracing tutorial, and many other online resrouces also.

The trick is the take the equation of the ray $\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}  = \boldsymbol{\vec{r}}_O + \lambda\, \boldsymbol{\hat{i}}$ and use it in the equation of the cylinder $R^2 =\left(\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}-\boldsymbol{\vec{r}_C}  - \boldsymbol{\hat{z}} \left( \boldsymbol{\hat{z}} \cdot (\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}-\boldsymbol{\vec{r}_C}) \right) \right)^2$ to solve for $\lambda$.

<sub>Note that $\boldsymbol{\vec{r}}^2 = r_x^2+r_y^2+r_z^2$ in this notation.</sub>

Comment: Thank you ja72 for this feedback and links. But my question is : can I turn this pretty difficult 3D problem (for me anyway) into two very simple 2D problems ?

Comment: I stand corrected. **No** is the answer then.